# How do I find and list duplicate rows based on columns in a CSV file using C#. Matching/Grouping Rows.

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I converted an excel file into a CSV file. The file contains over 100k records. I'm wanting to search and return duplicate rows by searching the full name column. If the full name's match up I want the program to return the entire rows of the duplicates. I started with a code that returns a list of full names but that's about it.

I've listed the code that I have now below:

```
public static void readCells()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        Console.WriteLine("started");
        var counter = 1;
        var readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        var duplicatedValues = dictionary.GroupBy(fullName => fullName.Value).Where(fullName => fullName.Count() > 1);

        foreach (var s in readText)
        {
            var values = s.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
            var fullName = values[3];
            if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(fullName))
            {
                dictionary.Add(fullName, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary[fullName] += 1;

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Full Name Is: " + values[3]);

            counter++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question in any of this.

Comment: Can you extend this to a [mcve] by including a CSV sample?

Answer (score 1):

I changed dictionary to use fullname as key :

```
       public static void readCells()
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>();

            Console.WriteLine("started");
            var counter = 1;
            var readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            var duplicatedValues = dictionary.GroupBy(fullName => fullName.Value).Where(fullName => fullName.Count() > 1);

            foreach (var s in readText)
            {
                List<string> values = s.Split(new Char[] { ',' }).ToList();
                string fullName = values[3];
                if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(fullName))
                {
                    List<List<string>> newList = new List<List<string>>();
                    newList.Add(values);
                    dictionary.Add(fullName, newList);
                }
                else
                {
                    dictionary[fullName].Add(values);

                }
                Console.WriteLine("Full Name Is: " + values[3]);

                counter++;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using Microsoft's built-in [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) (which you can use in c# despite being in the [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace) can simplify reading and parsing of CSV files.

Using this type, your method `ReadCells()` can be modified into the following extension method:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

public static class TextFieldParserExtensions
{
    public static List<IGrouping<string, string[]>> ReadCellsWithDuplicatedCellValues(string path, int keyCellIndex, int nRowsToSkip /* = 0 */)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(stream))
        {
            parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
            var values = parser.ReadAllFields()
                // If your CSV file contains header row(s) you can skip them by passing a value for nRowsToSkip
                .Skip(nRowsToSkip) 
                .GroupBy(row => row.ElementAtOrDefault(keyCellIndex))
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .ToList();
            return values;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string[]> ReadAllFields(this TextFieldParser parser)
    {
        if (parser == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
            yield return parser.ReadFields();
    }
}
```

Which you would call like:

```
var groups = TextFieldParserExtensions.ReadCellsWithDuplicatedCellValues(path, 3);
```

Notes:

- `TextFieldParser` correctly handles cells with escaped, embedded commas which `s.Split(new Char[] { ',' })` will not.
- Since your CSV file has over 100k records I adopted a streaming strategy to avoid the intermediate `string[] readText` memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library to parse CSV file and identify the duplicates with few lines of code.

Sample CSV file (EmpDuplicates.csv) below

```
Id,Name
1,Tom
2,Mark
3,Lou
3,Lou
4,Austin
4,Austin
4,Austin
```

Here is how you can parse and identify the duplicate records

```
using (var parser = new ChoCSVReader("EmpDuplicates.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    foreach (dynamic c in parser.GroupBy(r => r.Id).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()))
        Console.WriteLine(c.DumpAsJson());
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Id": 3,
  "Name": "Lou"
}
{
  "Id": 4,
  "Name": "Austin"
}
```

Hope this helps.

For more detailed usage of this library, visit CodeProject article at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1145337/Cinchoo-ETL-CSV-Reader